# Did Marty2 travel Back to the Future into a giant plot hole?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Please help me to figure this out. Born into a dysfunctional family, Marty1 alters his parents 1955 timeline. In this new, functional family timeline, Marty2 is born and raised until he disappears in his timeline's Delorean. Dysfunctional family timeline's Marty1 accomplished his mission and returned to Marty2's timeline, which left Marty2 nothing to alter in 1955(since Marty1 was already in 1955 doing the things shown the film), and as far as I can tell, Marty2 isn't represented in the rest of the trilogy. Did the film series leave a gaping plot hole, or am I just confused??

Comment: I'm not sure. None of those answers take into account that there was nothing that needed to be altered in Marty2's 1955. Marty1 went back and "fixed" his, and since Marty2 was born and grew up in that altered timeline, Marty2 had nothing that needed fixing in his 1955.

Comment: I'm not sure either, hence no VTC - just a comment.

Comment: You're just not thinking fourth-dimensionally.

Comment: Time is a Wibbly-Wobbly Timey-Wimey stuff...

Comment: Although this question has been marked as a duplicate and I can't put this in an answer, there is a slight nuance from the other question that I would like to address.  Specifically `which left Marty2 nothing to alter in 1955`.  This isn't a plot hole at all - Marty never left 1985 with the intent to fix his family's problems, in fact he never intended to leave at all, his main goal was to escape the terrorists after they apparently killed Doc Brown. His actions in 1955 did not change that need.

Comment: True, but once Marty2 escaped Marty1 had already done all of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 8):

You are thinking in a more quantum theory like way. That is not how Time Travel works in Back to the Future. In BttF, there is always only one timeline. If someone alters the timeline, the old timeline simply is deleted.

Marty1 and Marty2 are not two separate persons. Marty1 is the same person as the "new" Marty2, except he was not altered (he still has Marty1s memories) because he was "out of time" when the timeline was altered.

So basically Marty1s history gets replaced by Marty2s history up to the point where he leaves for 1955. But they still are the same person.

Comment: Well, technically they WERE two separate people for about 30 minutes, or however long it took Marty1 to run back to the mall and witness Marty2 race off in the DeLorean. After that, I assume they either merge into a single Marty (Marty1) or it's an infinite loop.

Comment: No, that is still the same Marty! The older one just does not remember because his memories basically overwrote the "new" memories.

Answer (score 2):

There is something that needs 'fixing' (was going to write this as a comment, but it makes more sense as an answer) - George needs to stand up to Biff, which doesn't happen unless Marty gets involved.

If Marty doesn't get involved, Biff ends up dominating Georges life, which causes the dysfunctionality we see later on.

So Marty still needs to go back in time to ensure he has his father stand up to Biff in the car park, altering their future relationship.

Comment: But since Marty1 was already in 1955(and always would be until something altered his timeline) doing  all of those things, Marty2 was... ?, doing what? I still think it`s a plothole.

Comment: @MajorStackings Marty2 is Marty1, completing the loop - its not a plot hole at all, it in-fact neatly wraps up the time travel theory used in BTTF in that there is only one time line you can travel up and down, and any changes affect that time line.  Your "Marty2" is in-fact Marty1 going back to effect the changes on the time line - there is no separate Marty2, he just overlaps himself by returning to the future minutes before he leaves.

Comment: I'm still confused. After Marty1 changes history, his parents live entirely different lives. Marty2 would not remember his dysfunctional family at all since he was born into the functional families timeline.

Comment: @MajorStackings who said he would? Its not as if Martys time trips were planned with a goal in mind...

Comment: I thought you did when you stated Marty1 was Marty2. Unless Marty1's 1955 actions altered his 1985 timeline only after Marty2 departed, the 2 Martys had to be distinct  individuals .

Comment: Now we are getting into a metaphysical discussion which revolves entirely around which version of time travel theory you subscribe to - yes, the Marty that returned to 1985 (Marty1) will have different experiences to the Marty that travels from 1985 to 1955 at the end of the film (Marty2). How that is resolved is anyone guess, but I dont count it as a plot hole.

Comment: @MajorStackings infact, there is only one time when there is infact two unrelated Martys in the same timeline (IE, Martys not involved in a loop) and that is during the second film, when Rich Biff is surprised at Prime Marty turning up when he is supposed to be off in some Swiss boarding school.